# Can I load multiple external api data from loader in Remix.run

Tags: remix.run

I am exploring Remix.run and I have a scenario where I need to execute multiple api calls initially.
Let's say a product list route with a dropdown, I need to load the products then the dropdown values from external APIs. Do I make both API calls in loader?

Answer (score 0):

If the API endpoint for the dropdown values relies on having a product selected you can just make the call in the selection event handler (*client side*).

If you want to make the call on the *server side* then it would make sense to use a [`useFetcher`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usefetcher), then on the selection handler call [`.submit()`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#fetchersubmit) passing the arguments as well as the action (if you want to use a [Resource Route](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes#creating-resource-routes) you need to pass its path, otherwise it will default to the component's closest route action) and method (defaults to **POST**) to use. Then retrieve the values in the component from [`.data`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#fetcherdata) when they come back from the endpoint.

In case both API calls are unrelated (a.k.a not having to select a product to feed the dropdown) then you might as well call both endpoints from the loader.

In any case, just make sure to fetch your data as soon as you have all the necessary data to do it (if that's on the loader step, do it then, if that's on an event handler, do it there).

Checkout Remix docs regarding [data loading](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/data-loading#data-loading).

Comment: Thanks for the options. When you say call both endpoints from the loader, do you mean to save both endpoint results in a variable then return them together? Or is there other proper way to do it in remix? Thanks in advance